# authorize chrome app as standalone in vkontakte api

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, vk

I'm trying to use vk.messages api in chrome app like this:

```
app.login = function () {
  var link = 'https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?' +
    'client_id=4837072' +
    '&scope=friends,docs,status,messages,notifications,' +
    '&redirect_uri=' + 'https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html' +
    '&display=popup' +
    '&v=API_VERSION' +
    '&response_type=token';
  var width = 655;
  var height = 539;
  var left = (screen.width / 2) - (width / 2);
  var top = (screen.height / 2) - (height / 2);
  chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({
    'url': link,
    'interactive': true
  }, function (redirect_url) {
    // redirect_url is undefined
    console.log(redirect_url);
  });
};
```

[It needs](https://vk.com/dev/auth_mobile) to set auth redirect_uri this way "https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html", but [chrome.identity  api](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity) uses "https://.chromiumapp.org/". So, vk auth window is showed and redirect works, but chrome can't determine auth redirect, and doesn't call back with redirect url. Is there any other way to get redirect url in chrome app?

Comment: Why can't you configure the OAuth app to be a website in stead of a desktop app? Chrome apps are kind of more web apps than desktop apps.

Comment: Because messages API available only for standalone apps

Comment: That's not my question. Just change your configuration on vk.com to be a website instead of a desktop app.

Comment: @abraham What is your point? OP tries to use APIs that are not exposed to "website" apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I see where you're going with "it needs to set `redirect_uri` this way":

> ```
> redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html
> ```
>
> It is a mandatory condition for methods which descriptions say that they are available only for Desktop applications.

I'm afraid there is no way to override the URL used by `identity` API.

<del>In this case, you can go kind of the same route Silver Bird Twitter client went: inject a [Content Script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) in the target address. From there you can extract the tokens needed.</del>

Edit: I forgot that you are writing a Chrome app. You should then try using `<webview>` and its script injection capabilities.

This means you'll have to do OAuth without help from `chrome.identity` yourself, but at least it's a solution.