# Custom url in chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to use chrome.identity with VK api for standalone app, which [requires](https://vk.com/dev/auth_mobile) setting redirect url to "https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html". Chrome can't parse with url, and doesn't return token. Is there any other way to do this in chrome app? May be i can create popup window, and handle by myself, if it is possible to catch redirect in js code?

Comment: How is this not answered in your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29200374/authorize-chrome-app-as-standalone-in-vkontakte-api ? My answer explicitly says "no".

Comment: Ah, okay. I see how my answer does not apply. Edited it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Xan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/934239/xan), there is `<webview>` [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29200507/1697248).

my code:

```
  webview.addEventListener("loadredirect", function(e) {
    if(e.newUrl.indexOf('access_token') > -1) {
      var result = e.newUrl.split('#')[1].split('&');
      app.token = result[0].split('=')[1];
      app.expires = result[1].split('=')[1];
      app.user_id = result[2].split('=')[1];
    }
  });
```